# Getting blank screen when trying to get data form mysql in json format

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a php file to get data from mysql database and display that data in json output, while accessing a certain url address like http://example.com/api/users.php

When I use following code I get json response:

```
<?php

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$servername = "localhost";

$username = "username";

$password = "password";

$dbname = "database";

//Connect to MySQL
$mysql = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$result_array = array();

$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
    
    $result = $mysql->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($result_array, $row);
        }
    }
    
    echo json_encode($result_array);
    $mysql->close();
?>
```

But when trying to get multiple cells from "users" row:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, avatar, email FROM users";
```

I get a blank screen in my web browser.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not simply `fetch_all()`?  Where exactly is `$result_array` declared before you try using it in `array_push()`?  Are you checking your error logs?  We don't know what columns your table has -- Needs Debugging Details.

Comment: 1) When using  `fetch_all()` I get a blank screen. Cells from users row are: username, email, avatar, password

Comment: Yes. `array_push()` demands it.  But that doesn't explain why your code works with one column and not three columns.

Comment: What does it mean "blank screen"? How do you check the response? Are you doing this in PostMan or just trying to view JSON in browser? Did you check your PHP error logs?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the PHP code you posted is returning a valid json when using single field then the basic code is correct. Now when you try to get multiple fields in the query its showing blank screen. This tells me that possibly your SQL `$sql = "SELECT username, avatar, email FROM users";` is throwing error. Try to run this sql statement directly on the database, there can be a mistake in column names.
So if the query fails, your $result_array is empty, and hence the json output is blank.